# can't display error page layouts in yii

Tags: yii

I am able to render my specified error pages in my modules, but I can't get error layouts outside of my modules.

It's quite strange, in my main config I have:

```
'errorHandler'=>array(
            'errorAction'=> '//site/error',
        ),
```

I tried to see if it is pointed to the right file by changing it to //site/contact, and see if it renders the contact page if error.  And it does show.

So the path is correct, then how come it's not showing the error page? It shows the default white page with exception error. The exception page is what im expecting, but how it's formatted is not.

```
public function actionError()
{
    $this->layout = '/layouts/main';
    if($error=Yii::app()->errorHandler->error)
    {
        if(Yii::app()->request->isAjaxRequest)
            echo $error['message'];
        else
            $this->render('error', array('error'=>$error));
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the exception error you get?

Comment: CHttpException You are not authorized to perform this action.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your user role doesn't have rights to access `actionError()` in controller.

In your site controller, You can see a function called `public function accessRules()`.

Check `error` is added for some user role, or it's for admin only.

If `error` not found, then add it for user roles.

**Example:**

```
public function accessRules()
        {
                return array(
                        array('allow',
                                                'actions' => array('index', 'view', 'error'),
                                                'users' => array('@')
                        ),
     ..
     ..
     ..
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a `errorXXX` in `views/system`. The XXX stand for the error code, in this case most likely a 403. For more information see [this page](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.error#displaying-errors) on the Yii site.